# Django: Get all sub related instances of the given instance

Tags: python, django

I would like to get all sub related instances of all classes that have reference to the given instance. I have tried using `related_name`, but it doesn't serve the purpose as it only gets all instances of one particular class, not all instances of all related classes. 
How could I achieve this?

**Model**

```
class AlertTypeMaster():
    alert_type_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class MachineAlertZone():
    machine_id = models.ForeignKey(MachineMaster, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    alert_type_id = models.ForeignKey(AlertTypeMaster, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    radius_value = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class ActivityRecording():
    alert_type_id = models.ForeignKey(AlertTypeMaster, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    working_area_id = models.ForeignKey(WorkingAreaMaster, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    staff_id = models.ForeignKey(StaffMaster, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    type_of_occur = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Given the one object of `AlertTypeMaster`, I should be able to get all objects from both `MachineAlertZone` and `ActivityRecording`.

Please suggest any suitable approaches!

Comment: Your models don't inherit from `models.Model`. If you fix that, everything else looks correct and the delete behavior should be cascade.

Comment: @shacker I want to get all the related instances only, I'm not doing the cascade delete operation.

Comment: Oh I understand now. But get them as *what*? Queryset won't work. I think your assumptions need a bit of tweaking and you'd be better off redesigning your models and code. The child objects should *not* need their own `active` bools - calling code should get that from the parent.Delete that field from both child models!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't mix instances from different models in a same queryset (the reasons seem obvious enough when you remember that models and querysets are just thin layers over a relational database).

Now nothing prevents you from providing your own iterable. At the simplest, you just chain together both querysets in a generator ie:

```
import itertools

def iter_subs(self):
    yield from itertools.chain(self.machinealertzone_set.all(), self.activityrecording_set.all())
```

or anything more elaborate (sorting 'sub' objects by some criteria etc) depending on your needs.

This being said, I don't really see the point... Given your models definitions (few common fields and no common operations), this will be a very heterogenous collection and you will probably have to typecheck each item during iteration to know what to do with it, which kind of defeats the whole point of retrieveing them all at once.

**EDIT**

> I need to retrieve them all at once because when one AlertTypeMaster object active field is set to True, all the sub object active field need to be set to True also. In case my approach is not efficient, could you suggest a better way?

This is denormalization. Do you really need it ? If the MachineAlertZone and ActivityRecording `status` is supposed to reflect their AlertTypeMaster, then the proper design (theoretically, according to relational model normal forms) is to just get the status directly from the AlertTypeMaster:

```
class StatusQueryset(models.Queryset):
    # allow to filter MachineAlertZone and ActivityRecording
    # by their parent AlertType active status
    def active(self):
        return self.filter(alert_type__active=True)

class MachineAlertZone():
    machine = models.ForeignKey(MachineMaster, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    alert_type = models.ForeignKey(AlertTypeMaster, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    radius_value = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    #active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    @property
    def active(self):
        return self.alert_type.status

    objects = StatusQueryset.as_manager()
```

But if you still want to keep an individual flag for your "submodels", you still don't need to "retrieve them all at once" to update their status - just issue two update queries in a transaction in your `AlertTypeMaster.save()` method:

```
from django.db import transaction

class AlertTypeMaster(models.Model):
    def save(self, *args, **kw):
        with transaction.atomic():
            super(AlertTypeMaster, self).save(*args, **kw)
            self.machinealertzone_set.update(active=self.active)
            self.activityrecording_set.update(active=self.active)
```

Comment: I need to retrieve them all at once because when one `AlertTypeMaster` object `active` field is set to `True`, all the sub object `active` field need to be set to `True` also. In case my approach is not efficient, could you suggest a better way?

Comment: If your approach consist in iterating over each related submodel instance individually, update it's active flag and save it,then it's indeed far from efficient. I've edited my answer with two possible solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You always have to keep in mind the DB structure under Django models. Appending two querysets of two different models is impossible, because the resulting "queryset" would loose it's capabilities. What would you do on update? What fields would you be able to filter on?

One option is to fetch both querysets, evaluate them as lists and merge the two lists, which is essentially what bruno suggests (the generator approach is more memory efficent than simple list merge).

Better solution would be to rethink your models. Think this for example:

```
class AlertTypeMaster():
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class MachineAlertZone():
    machine_id = models.ForeignKey(MachineMaster, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    alert_type_id = models.ForeignKey(AlertTypeMaster, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    radius_value = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class ActivityRecording():
    working_area_id = models.ForeignKey(WorkingAreaMaster, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    staff_id = models.ForeignKey(StaffMaster, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    type_of_occur = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Alert():
    alert_type_id = models.ForeignKey(AlertTypeMaster, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='alerts')
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    zone = model.ForeignKey(MachineAlertZone, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    activity = model.ForeignKey(ActivityRecording, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.CheckConstraint(
                check=models.Q(
                    zone__isnull=False,
                    activity__isnull=True) | 
                models.Q(
                    zone__isnull=True,
                    activity__isnull=False),
                name='activity_zone_xor'
            )
        ]
```

You can call:

```
alert_type_master.alerts.all().select_related('zone', 'activity')
```

This way you fetch all the zones and activities of your alert_type_master in a single query. The Meta defined constraint makes sure that only activity or only zone is present on a given alert.

Setting an alert to active=True for a fiven master becomes as easy as:

```
alert_type_master.alerts.all().update(active=True)
```

A detail I would also rethink in your code is calling ForeignKey fields as "id". It is not really just id, in the database it is, but not in Django.

```
MachineAlertZone.object.first().machine_id  # this returns an object, not an id
```

Comment: "evaluate them as lists and merge the two lists, which is essentially what bruno suggests." => well, not quite - I suggested using lazy evaluation (a generator or other iterator) ;-)

Comment: The querysets get evaluated and saved in memory anyway, so what's the difference?

Comment: "what's the difference?" => first, this avoids doing anything until the iterable is effectively iterated, and then it avoids building an additional list - even if the model instances are shared between the queryset's inner cache and your own list, the list _still_ uses memory - and I have no idea of the OP's datasets size... of course if there's like a dozen related records per "master", a list is definitly not an issue ;-)

Comment: True, fair enough, added that in the answer :)